# Pass VF component attribute to component extension

Tags: visualforce-component, extension

Following is my code:

**VF PAGE:**

```
<apex:page standardController="account" extensions="ForecastHierarchyEditExtension" tabStyle="Account" sidebar="false"  standardStylesheets="false">                            
    <c:ForecastHierarchyEdit recordId="{!account.id}"/>  
</apex:page>
```

**VF COMPONENT used in above page:**

```
<apex:component Controller="ForecastHierarchyController" extensions="ForecastHierarchyEditCompExtension">
    <apex:attribute name="recordId" description="Record Id" type="id" assignTo="{!record_Id}" required="true"/>
    <apex:form >
        <apex:selectList value="{!ForecastCustomerToDelete}" multiselect="false">
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!ForecastCustomers}"/>  
        </apex:selectList>
    </apex:form>
</apex:component>
```

**COMPONENT CUSTOM CONTROLLER:**

```
public class ForecastHierarchyController { 

    public account acc{get;set;}
    public id record_Id;
    public id getrecord_Id(){
         return record_Id; 
    } 

    //Following is the solution for record_Id null in the constructor
    public void setrecord_Id(id s){
        if (s!=null){
          record_Id = s;
          GetData();
        }
   }


    public ForecastHierarchyController() { 
          /*Since the constructor is called before the setter
          record_Id will always be null when the constructor is called.*/                      
          system.debug('record_Id '+record_Id);      
    }

    public void GetData(){
        acc=[select Id
            from account
            where id=:record_Id];
        system.debug('Component Controller acct '+acc);
    }
}
```

**COMPONENT EXTENSION CONTROLLER:**

```
public class ForecastHierarchyEditCompExtension {
    public id ForecastCustomerToDelete { get; set; }
    private final ForecastHierarchyController myReference;   
    private final Account acct;


    public ForecastHierarchyEditCompExtension (ForecastHierarchyController ForecastHierarchyCtrl) {
         this.myReference = ForecastHierarchyCtrl;
          System.debug('myReference: ' + myReference);
          acct=myReference.acc;
    }   


    public List<SelectOption> ForecastCustomers{
        get {
            List<SelectOption> ForecastCustomers = new List<SelectOption>(); 
            //here acct=null
            system.debug('Component Controller Extension acct '+acct);
            if (acct!=null){
                if (acct.id!=null){             
                    for (account acc :[select id,Name from account where Forecast_Account__c=: acct.id]){
                        ForecastCustomers.add( new SelectOption( acc.id, acc.Name ) ); 
                    }        
                } 
            }     
            return ForecastCustomers;
        }
        private set;
    } 

}
```

[image]

I know that we cannot access the attribute **record_Id** in the constructor of the VF component controller (null value) so i m setting it with

```
public void setrecord_Id(id s){
```

How can i pass  **record_Id**  to the component extension controller ?
I mean to ForecastHierarchyEditCompExtension  constructor.

I would like to get populate **myReference.acc** or **myReference.record_Id** so that also List ForecastCustomers will be populated.

Actually List  is not populated because acct is null.

Thanks in advantage for any advice.

Comment: I'm not sure yet why record_Id is null, but I think I see a problem that hasn't come up yet:  The extension constructor references acc in the custom controller, but, at the time the extension constructor runs, acc won't have been set.  (Both constructors will run before the getters/setters, and acc is set by GetData(), which is called by setrecord_ID.)

Comment: Yes Shane, that is the problem that i m trying to solve.

Comment: Oh.  Oops!  I was focused on the null mystery.  :P

Comment: Did you find a solution ?